# Laravel Error: Too few arguments to function, 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

```
public function manager_employee_list(Request $request)
{

    $employees = HrEmployee::paginate(6);

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_list')->with('employees', $employees);
}
```

And it render this view: manager_employee_list

```
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
          @if (count($employees))
          @foreach($employees as $key => $employee)
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-header text-muted border-bottom-0">
              {{isset($employee->designation) ? $employee->designation->designation_name : ''}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-0">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                  <h2 class="lead"><b>Staff ID: {{$employee->employee_code}}</b></h2>
                  <h2 class="lead"><b>{{$employee->first_name}} {{$employee->last_name}}</b></h2>

                  <h6 class="lead"><b>Employee Department: </b>{{isset($employee->department) ? $employee->department->dept_name : ''}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5 text-center">
                            @if($employee->emp_image != '')
                                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/public/storage/employees/image/{{ $employee->emp_image }}" class="img-circle img-fluid" />

                            @else
                                <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" src="{{asset('theme/adminlte3/dist/img/default.png')}}" alt="" class="img-circle img-fluid">
                            @endif
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <div class="text-right">
                <a href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal', ['id'=>$employee->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i> View Goal
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach 
        @else
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">No matching records found</h4>
        @endif           
      </div>
```

I want to pass the parameter

['id'=>$employee->id]

from above to another controller action:

```
public function manager_employee_goal($id)
{

    $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $id)->get();

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal')->with('goals', $goals);        
}
```

It utilizes it here:

> $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $id)->get();

When I clicked on

```
<a href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal', ['id'=>$employee->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
     <i class="fas fa-user"></i> View Goal
</a>
```

I got this error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController::manager_employee_goal(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

and this is underlined:

> public function manager_employee_goal($id)

route/web.php

```
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_list', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_list')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_list');
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
```

How do I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can check the url that is being created using inspect element. It seems your are missing $employee->id

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in your `web.php` file. add `{id}` in URL.

otherwise, all are fine as now your get method will be like `'appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id}'`

```
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id}','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
```

Comment: @Khushbu - I changed the web.php file to appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id}    but got another error:          Eror 404  Page not found.   But the page is available

Comment: select the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your route need to be updated to

```
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id}','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
```